# Why in C# the answer of (++x - --x) is always 1 for every value of x? Why not 0?

Tags: c#

I don't understand why in C#, `++x - --x` is 1 for every value of `x`.

`int x = 0;`

`Console.WriteLine(++x - --x); // gives 1`

I believe the answer should be 0, as variable `x` involves both sides. And `x` is incremented and decrimented before the processing of substraction. The same equation in C++  returns 0, that make sense to me.

Can anyone give a clue what's actually happening here?

Comment: C# or C++? In C++ this is undefined behaviour, so that it returns `0` means nothing. It could return .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior. I don't know if it is undefined behaviour in C#, but code like this is nonsense anyway.

Comment: "*And x is incremented and decrimented before the processing of substraction*" this is your assumption, turns out its wrong though

Comment: Those kinds of questions have been answered a thousand times on this site alone. The actual answer should be: Do not _ever_ write such code. It is a stupid idea to do so, because of exactly that kind of confusion it causes. C++ does the right thing by making it a garbage statement, therefore discouraging its use. Separate your code into lines you can understand and you'll be much happier.

Comment: If you look at the IL you will see clearly, https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAlgGwD4AEBMBGAsAKHQGYACLEgYRIG8CT6zT0oSBZACgEoa6G+A3AIYAnEmBIBeEgAYA3Lz7102AJzsA1OvEBaEtu1hO8/HwC+BU0A

Comment: Just to be clear, @TheGeneral, that's not *always* a reliable indicator. I could look at the machine code generated by `gcc` and still not be any wiser as to whether it was guaranteed. In this case, it is, but that's more down to the language spec than to the underlying IL.

Comment: @paxdiablo though I agree, in this case it is easy to see, it loads , pushes 1, adds, copies, pushes 1, subtracts copies pops and subtracts. Though the IL was pointless, as the result speaks for itself

Answer (score 8):

This is actually undefined behaviour in C and C++. For example, C states that reading and modifying an object without an intervening sequence point is undefined.

However, C# locks down the behaviour so that behaviour *is* defined. From the [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/):

> Unrelated to operator precedence and associativity, operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right. The following examples demonstrate the order in which operators and operands are evaluated:
>
> `OPERAND EVALUATION`
> `Expression             Order of evaluation`
> `a + b                  a, b, +`
> `a + b * c              a, b, c, *, +`
> `a / b + c * d          a, b, /, c, d, *, +`
> `a / (b + c) * d        a, b, c, +, /, d, *`

And, from the [operator precedence table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), you can see that `++x` (unary category) has a higher precedence than `x + y` (additive category).

In your case, the sub-expression `++x` is evaluated first and results in `x` being pre-incremented so the value of that sub-expression is the original `x` plus one.

*Then* the sub-expression `--x` is evaluated and results in `x` (already incremented from the previous step) being pre-decremented so the value of that sub-expression is the original `x`.

And, since `x + 1 - x == 1` for all but the *darkest* corners of the math universe, the result is always one. I still wouldn't *do* something like this, but it at least is well defined.